# Python (SymPy, SciPy), create symbol lambda from string

Tags: python, lambda, scipy, integral

I've struggling to take text inputs of an equation and evaluate it as a definite integral. I need a callable function to pass to `scipy.integrate`.

```
eq = "x**2"
func = lambda x: eq
func(2)

# outputs:
# x**2


# but if I:

func = lambda x: x**2
func(2)

# outputs:
# 4
```

Comment: Your second code snippet does not use `sympy` at all.  The lines `from sympy import Symbol; x = Symbol('x')` have no effect.

Comment: haha. wow, good catch, I never would have realized. I feel silly. thanks! None the less though, my problem remains.

Comment: For reference:  While this is not what you want to pass to scipy.integrate, the way you get a sympy expression from a string is to use `sympify`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010583/mathematical-equation-manipulation-in-python/1010666#1010666

Answer (score 5):

Not sure, but maybe you are looking for

```
eq = "x**2"
func = eval("lambda x: " + eq)
```

Note that using `eval()` is dangerous if `eq` is from an untrusted source (e.g. user input).

Comment: This post explains how to safely handle user input with `eval`: http://lybniz2.sourceforge.net/safeeval.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to use eval to run eq as code and not treat it as a string.

```
eq = "x**2"
func = lambda x: eval(eq)
func(2)

# outputs:
# 4
```

Answer (score 2):

[sympify](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/core.html?highlight=sympify#sympy.core.sympify) may be what you are looking for. It converts a string expression into an sympy object.

For example:

```
import sympy as sp
f=sp.sympify('x**2+sin(y)')
```

And you can use [autowrap](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/utilities/autowrap.html?highlight=autowrap#sympy.utilities.autowrap) to convert a sympy object into a callable function.

Comment: Instead of autowrap, you could declare x and y as symbols, EG `x, y = sympy.symbols('x y')`, then call `evalf` with `subs` and pass in the arguments, EG `f.evalf(subs={x:1.23, y:4.56})` returns 0.524488748060870

Answer (score 1):

Try [asteval](http://newville.github.io/asteval/) or [numexpr](https://code.google.com/p/numexpr/) for possibly safer alternatives to eval() and Sympy.sympify().evalf().

Answer (score 0):

I continually got a syntax error for the following and relentlessly was trying to find out why:

```
E="2x+1"
F=lambda x: (x, eval(E)) # to get an xy coordinate
```

But the issue worked as expected when I changed E to:

```
E="2*x+1"
```

Rookie mistake. :)