# Solving an equation for a variable

Tags: python, sympy

How can I get this to give me x = z*y/a ?

```
from sympy import *

x,y,a,z = symbols('x y a z')
z = a*x/y

solve(z,x) # returns 0!
           # would like to get z*y/a
```

Comment: I highly suggest that you [use an IDE](http://sopython.com/wiki/Python_IDEs). It will help you learn python much faster and help avoid trivial mistakes  like assigning a new value to the name `z` as described by user2357112 [in his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35808171/4230591). (you are making `z` a symbol, then by doing `z=...` it ceases to be that symbol). This error is somewhat unrelated to your actual question though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`solve(z,x)` correctly returns 0 because your code is effectively asking:

> What's the value of x that would cause z to become 0?

What you really want to do (as described [here](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/solvers.html#algebraic-equations)) is solve `a*x/y==z` which can be done as follows:

```
from sympy import *

x,y,a,z = symbols('x y a z')
equation = a*x/y

new_eq = solve(equation - z, x)  # its value is [y*z/a]
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't assign `z = a*x/y`, and don't pass `z` to `solve`.

`solve(expr, symbol)` determines what values of `symbol` will make `expr` equal 0. If you want to figure out what value of `x` makes `z` equal `a*x/y`, you want `z - a*x/y` to equal 0:

```
solve(z - a*x/y, x)
```

You do *not* want to assign `z = a*x/y`. `=` means something entirely different from equality.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010583/mathematical-equation-manipulation-in-python) can be of help. Applied to your example, this gives:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x,y,a,z = symbols('x y a z')
>>> l = z
>>> r = a*x/y
>>> solve(l-r,x)
[y*z/a]
```

Answer (score 0):

As all the other answers points out the solution,
I would like to emphasize on the use of `Eq` instances here.
An `Eq` object represents `An equal relation between two objects.`

For using an `Eq` object, your code should look something like this:

```
In []: a, x, y, z = symbols('a, x, y, z')  
In []: foo = Eq(z, a*x/y)
In []: solve(foo, x)
Out[]: [y*z/a]
```